# open source code visualization plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

is there a code visualization plugin for eclipse?

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/code-rocket-eclipse

it's too expensive however so is there a open source version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ModelGoon](http://www.modelgoon.org/) is probably the most promising open source project for code visualization based on Eclipse JDT. [GreenUML](http://green.sourceforge.net/) may also be of interest, but it doesn't seem too active. I even had to patch a few things to get it working properly in my case ([see my github fork](https://github.com/fmjrey/Green-UML)).

If you want visualization based on runtime capture of program execution you may want to see this [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/step-back-in-eclipse-debugger/4561350#4561350).

Finally you may want to explore the [Source Code Analyzer category on Eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/14), the listing is a bit broader in scope and includes both proprietary and open source solutions.