# Recording step by step execution path of application in Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for Java development. Is there a way to record step by step execution  of the program while debugging so that it can be compared with the next runs of the program?

Comment: You could probably try the recording the screen during your first run and compare it with your next run output.

Answer (score 0):

See this question related to Eclipse: [How to step back in Eclipse debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/step-back-in-eclipse-debugger)

Short answer: I'm not aware of anything that does that in Netbeans, but for Eclipse there are several plugins, Jive for example.