# Debugging the java class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Step back in Eclipse debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/step-back-in-eclipse-debugger)

I have been debugging my project in eclipse and putting breakpoint at several classes and pressing F6 in eclipse and moving forward from one breakpoint to another breakpoint but what about IF i want to move backward that is to the previous breakpoint in reverse flow is there any shortcut for that as F6 takes us to forward what about backward Please advise..!

Comment: Java debuggers don't have that feature like in Visual Studio AFAIK.

Comment: Perhaps this may help. There was already article.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/step-back-in-eclipse-debugger

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "Drop to frame" action which brings you back to the beginning of the function.
By default there is no key associated to this but you can associate one in "Window / Preferences / General / Keys".
But you can not go to the previous breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way in eclipse, but you can set the code up to return to a previous point after running a method. Use

```
//declare a method
public void methodName()
{
    //code
}
```

To make a method. To call the method, use

```
methodName();
```

Which will run the method then return to the previous point.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you can do is that if Object `A` calls `B` and `B` calls `C` your debugger is in `C` and you want to see variables/etc in object `A`, you can select `A` from the thread trace in debugger window and see that.

**Debugger flow doesn't move backwards** i.e. if there are two steps: `step-1` and `step-2` and `step-1` is complete, control is at `step-2`, the you can't go back to `step-1`.