# how to find which method called a specific method with break point in it

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

As I was debugging my code, I placed a break point within a method called `getDate()`.

I ran my code and execution halted right on my break point, which is great.

But is there a way in Eclipse or (preferably) Android Studio to find out which method called `getDate()` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/step-back-in-eclipse-debugger might help

Comment: This is a bit about a tutorial and a bit about a software... Not sure it suits Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is a simple way. On Android studio it's called `Frames` perspective, and it is part of the debugger perspective. When your app stops on a breakpoint you can inspect the whole chain of callers

[image]

picture is taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html)

Comment: can you provide some steps on how to do that ?

Comment: you don't have to do nothing. If want jump to the caller, you have only to click on one of the *Frames*

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse, you can see the thread sequence in debug mode.

Or you can go to call hierarchy by selecting a particular method.

Comment: can you provide some steps on how to do that ?

Comment: _http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-droptoframe.htm_ this might help.