# Can I say to the Eclipse debugger to come back to the previous step?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have the following doubt about the Eclipse debugger dbugging a Java application.

When it stop on a break point I know that I can go to the next step. But can I also go to the previous one?

Comment: yes, you can...in the debug view under the debug tab, you can click on the steps where your code ran...if I remember well

Comment: also you can take a look at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/step-back-in-eclipse-debugger

Comment: No you cannot. But there are tools like chronon that record the execution and can do that

Answer (score 0):

The best compromise is "Drop to Frame" (one of the icons in the debugging area), which essentially resets the stack frame and puts you at the top of the method.  This won't reset any external side effects, so if some code between the top of the method and your current position changed any properties of an object, you'll have to deal with that.