# how do i take step reverse while doing debugging in eclipse ide for java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ide

it happens to me many times: I'm stepping with the debugger through my code, and ups! i made one step too far! Debugging, and made one step over too far[image]

what now? restart the whole debugging session?

actually, there is a way to go ‘backwards’

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331336/how-to-step-back-in-eclipse-debugger . Please check in SO before posting your questions as other users may downvote or close your question.

Comment: You can't go back one line , but you  can  move to previous point or function start

Answer (score 2):

The feature is called 'Drop to frame' right click on any line in stack, choose 'Drop to frame' and you go back to selected method beginning

https://help.eclipse.org/2021-03/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-droptoframe.htm

You can only jump to the start of the current function . Please keep that in mind.

[image: Drop to Frame]

Comment: And if it's not obvious, "Drop to Frame" will not be able to reset any changes that were made to objects in the heap between the first line and the line you reached when you clicked "Drop to Frame".